# What is the difference between Magento CE 2.1.4 and 2.1.5?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.4, magento2.1.5

What is the difference between Magento CE 2.1.4 and 2.1.5?

Which bugs are solved in Magento CE2.1.5?

What are the differences with previous Magento CE?

Comment: Did you not read the [Magento CE 2.1.5 Release Notes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.5CE.html)?  Frankly, I would vote to close, if I had the reputation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There are not any functional bug resolved in Magento 2.1.5**

Only Difference is updates of copyright date in each file.

**See Comment from Magento devdocs file,**

> This release updates the copyright date in every file. It does not
>   contain any functional changes or security improvements. Isolating
>   these changes in a single release is intended to simplify future
>   updates and developer workflow.

[Magento Devdocs release note link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.5CE.html)

From Magento 2.1.5,

Only Date changes in every file of magento source,
**You can check it in every file with comment of copyright date start with something like below,**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
```

You can check it in magento 2.1.4 file with copyright date as below,

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
```